# How do I return an object to a previous frame that is still open?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have a main frame which has an array list containing a list of items for an order. I then have a button which creates a new window that has a form allowing the user to pick multiple options for an item, this information is then put into an object.

I want to return this object back to the original frame so that I can add it to the order array list. However I'm not sure how to go about this as my frames have their code auto generated as I'm using netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a listener (interface) system. Create an interface and implement it in your main frame, when you create your second frame you pass the first one as parameter. By this way you will be able to call a method, let's say, onItemSelected in the second frame whenever you want in an elegant way.
Using interfaces is more convenient, you can have multiple listener.

There is an example:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ItemSelectedListener {

    void onButtonClick() {
        new SecondFrame(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(List<String> items) {
        // do your stuff with the selected items here
    }

}

interface ItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(List<String> items);
}

class SecondFrame extends JFrame {

    private ItemSelectedListener    itemSelectedListener;
    private JTextField              name;
    private JButton                 buttonOk;

    SecondFrame(ItemSelectedListener listener) {
        itemSelectedListener = listener;

        name = new JTextField();
        buttonOk = new JButton("OK");
        getContentPane().add(name);
        getContentPane().add(buttonOk);

        buttonOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                List<String> myFormItems = new ArrayList<>();
                // fulfill your list with all informations that you need
                myFormItems.add(name.getText());
                // notify your main frame that the user finished to complete the form
                itemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(myFormItems);
            }
        });
    }

}
```